# Measure timing of terraform apply execution time

Tags: terraform, timing

Is there a way to measure timing of `terraform apply` command in interactive mode? I know I can run it with `-auto-approve` and capture time before and after, but in interactive mode user is prompted with "Do you want to execute?" message and can be stuck there for indeterminate amount of time. In this scenario is there a way to measure actual execution time?

Answer (score 1):

In the command line, enter `time terraform apply`